# Two phase type inference confusion

Tags: c#, generics

I was reading C# in depth , got confused in 2-phase type inference rule explained by dear author.

Consider the code :

```
static void PrintConvertedValue<TInput,TOutput> (TInput input, Converter<TInput,TOutput> converter) 
{ Console.WriteLine(converter(input)); } 
... 
PrintConvertedValue("I'm a string", x => x.Length);
```

after which he explains the process of inference using 2-phase inference algo.

> 1.Phase 1 begins.
>
> 2.**The first parameter is of type TInput, and the first argument is of type string. We infer that there must be an implicit conversion from
>   string to TInput.**
>
> 3.The second parameter is of type Converter, and the second argument is an implicitly typed lambda expression. No inference
>   is performed—we don’t have enough information.
>
> 4.Phase 2 begins.
>
> 5.**`TInput` doesn’t depend on any unfixed type parameters, so it’s fixed to string.**
>
> 6.The second argument now has a fixed input type, but an unfixed output type. We can consider it to be `(string x) => x.Length` and infer
>   the return type as int. Therefore an implicit conversion must take
>   place from int to `TOutput`.
>
> 7.Phase 2 repeats.
>
> 8.`TOutput` doesn’t depend on anything unfixed, so it’s fixed to int. 9There are now no unfixed type parameters, so inference succeeds

I am very confused with step 2 and step 5. In step 2 how can compiler make inference like that ? I mean how in world conversion comes in to the scene? Conversion happens BTW types not BTW type parameters and types, isn't it?.

And step 5 completely eluded me, can anyone present me simplified example where a type parameter can depend on other type parameter please with explanation what author is trying to imply?

I dared to lurk in to C# specification but seems intelligent peoples made it for very similar intelligent peoples, not for monkeys like me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conversion happens for *values*, and the fact that we're able to call the method using a string value as the argument for a parameter of type `TInput` means that there must be a conversion from `string` to `TInput`. If `TInput` were inferred to be `int`, then we'd be calling a method requiring an `int`, but giving it a `string` - which is clearly not valid.

Note that for a simpler example, just change it to:

```
void Foo<T>(T input) { }
```

called with:

```
Foo("Hello");
```

There has to be a conversion from `string` to `T` in order for the call to be valid, and as there's no *other* information about `T`, we infer that `T` is simply `string`.

In a slightly more complicated example, you could have:

```
public void Bar<T>(T x, T y) {}

Foo("Hello", new object());
```

Here, we infer that:

- There must be a conversion from `string` to `T`
- There must be a conversion from `object` to `T`

... so we infer that `T` is `object`.

As for type parameter dependencies, from section 7.5.2.5 of the C# 5 specification:

> An unfixed type variable Xi depends directly on an unfixed type variable Xj if for some argument Ek with type Tk Xj occurs in an input type of Ek with type Tk and Xi occurs in an output type of Ek with type Tk.
>
> Xj depends on Xi if Xj depends directly on Xi or if Xi depends directly on Xk and Xk depends on Xj. Thus “depends on” is the transitive but not reflexive closure of “depends directly on”.

So for example:

```
public void Foo<T1, T2>(T1 value, Func<T1, T2> func)
```

And:

```
Foo("foo", x => x.Length);
```

Here `T2` depends on `T1` - once we've inferred `T1`, we can infer `T2`.

Comment: Can you present simple example presenting the idea from your first para please?. I still don't get your conversion theory, sorry :( . P.S it feels awesome when author himself helps :D

Comment: @HolyKiller: I've edited my answer to give a version with just one type parameter and one parameter / argument.

Comment: I have c++ background a bit and there is no such conversion theory btw template argument and type parameter in c++, that's why I got confused.

Comment: @HolyKiller: I would try *not* to treat generics and C++ templates as if they were the same - they're very definitely not.